# Less CSS lines for better performance?

Tags: css, microbenchmark

Obviously there's two groups of coders:

Group 1:

```css
#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Group 2:

```css
#wrapper {margin: 0 auto;}
```

What method are the most efficient? Do group 2 get better performance because of less lines?

Comment: Write it however you want. [Minify](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources) the result and serve it compressed to optimize load times.

Comment: Are you talking about **downloading** or **processing** performances ?

Comment: Are all of you seriosly think that spaces eat performance? I'd rather optimize more meaningful things.

Answer (score 3):

The parser will read the file top to bottom. So the less lines it has to read the better. In terms of performance, the second example is superior. But minifying eliminates this issue altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your two examples with more than one rules instead:

**Group 1**:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Group 2**:

```
#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px 5px; text-transform: uppercase; }
```

The first approach is easier to maintain and much more readable to the maintainer (usually a human, not always guaranteed). If you [minify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) your CSS and JavaScript then your writing style won't matter as minification will take care of such concerns for you. Try pasting my Group 1 code on [cssminifier.com](http://cssminifier.com) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it improves performance, hence the existence of minification tools. That said, don't start developing your code in a single line like that as there's no readability.

Write the code out as you are doing for readability and then minify the result as the commenter said.